# I want to access UserQus.append(msg) and BotAns.append(res) out of send() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

1.This is my code here you can see the send() method. I want to use UserQus and BotAns out of send method in on_closing() method for sore in firebase database, I can't do it so, please give me solution for it.

```
# Creating GUI with tkinter
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

base = Tk()
# from firebase import firebase
UserQus = []
BotAns = []

# This method is for tkinter button
def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 14))

        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "Bot: " + res + '\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
# here msg an res are append in UserQus and BotAns
    UserQus.append(msg)
    BotAns.append(res)


def on_closing():
    from firebase import firebase
    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://fir-demopython.firebaseio.com/', None)
# here UserQus and BotAns are sore in data variable for define in firebase.post() # that store in database
    data = {'You': UserQus, 'Bot': BotAns}
    res = firebase.post('fir-demopython/DemoTbl', data)
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        base.destroy()
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying `on_closing` above it's first call (e.g. at the top of `send`)?

Comment: you should call on_closing() after you have defined it. Move on_closing() function to the first line of your send() function

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply: you are defining the `on_closing()` function **within** the `send()` function. This means that 1/ it's created anew each time `send` is called, and 2/ it's only visible within the `send` function (it's a local variable).

Just move your `on_closing()` definition *outside* the `send()` function (and move your imports at the top level too), and the problem is solved:

```
# imports should NOT be in functions
from firebase import firebase

def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)
    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12))

        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "Bot: " + res + '\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
    UserQus.append(msg)
    BotAns.append(res)

# and this should not be defined within the `send()` function, of course
def on_closing():
    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://fir-demopython.firebaseio.com/', None)
    data = {'You': UserQus, 'Bot': BotAns}
    res = firebase.post('fir-demopython/DemoTbl', data)
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        base.destroy()
```

Comment: But I want to store msg and res into firebase(real-time) database.
So, I want to use msg and res data members of send method.

Comment: @YashTank I have no idea what you want to do, nor what "msg" and "res" are, etc etc etc. You ask why you can't access the `on_closing()` function outside the `send()` function and how to fix it, I answer on those two points. I didn't even bothered reading the rest of the code as it's totally irrelevant here (and not even a proper [mcve] FWIW).

Comment: I edit my question, so please check it. and can you give me answer again.